# Improper Beautiful Soup Parsing

Tags: python, parsing, url, beautifulsoup

With this code I am getting the following URL from BS parsing:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "(FROM 'tiffany@e.tiffany.com')") # search and return uids instead
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]

html = raw_email
soup = BS(html)

urls=[]
for x in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    urls.append(x['href'])

print urls
```

Output

```
'3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/6EN2U/52/h"='
```

How can i strip the first 4 and last 3 characters? Is it something I can do in beautiful soup or should I use split()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str.lstrip()` and `rstrip()`. The drawback of this method is, you'll have to exactly now what you want to remove.

Here, stripping all the urls, as you put them into a list:

```
urls.append(x['href'].lstrip("'3D\"").rstrip("\"=\'"))
```

Comment: thank you! do you know if this could have been accomplished with beautiful soup?